# Linear Programming in Mata with panel data - looping over individuals, specifying objective function

Tags: optimization, stata, linear-programming, panel-data

I try to use linear programming in Mata.

I would like to assign an education category (z,s,v = low, middle, high) to each individual according to probabilities obtained previously by odered probit. I also have a marginal distribution for each category in the population.

P* are my probabilities for each category, Q* is a number of individuals in each educational category in the population.

I would like to optimize something like that:

Objective function maximising the probabilities = choose the most probable education category subject to marginal distribution:

```
max∑ (PzXz + PsXs + PvXv)

X should be 1 or 0 

∑Xz  = Qz, ∑Xs  = Qs, ∑Xv  = Qv
```

I obtain this error message:

```
invalid dimension of coefficients The coefficients must be a rowvector with length at least 1.
```

and it comes after this line

```
 X[i,.] = lp.parameters()   // Store parameter
```

For Q* I am aware that I should specify a scalar instead of a vector of the same number, that was just my variable from STATA I merged with the distributional data but not sure hot to do that (local marcos did not work out).

Other than that I do not know where to start to solve my problem. I would like to obtain a matrix of three variables X telling me which category has to be choosen subject to marginal distribution.

I would be thankful for any advice/hints, what to consider.

```
clear
input float(Pz Ps Pv Qz Qs Qv) 
 .0226813 .8045667    .172752 3 5 2
.09679342 .8531785  .05002809 3 5 2
.06026781 .8577851   .0819471 3 5 2
.15252922 .8199771 .027493654 3 5 2
.24786794 .7403268 .011805267 3 5 2
 .0226813 .8045667    .172752 3 5 2
.09538278 .8537293   .0508879 3 5 2
.05995392 .8576999  .08234616 3 5 2
.08492604 .8570921  .05798185 3 5 2
.09858042 .8524512  .04896835 3 5 2
end
```

```
putmata Pz Ps Pv Qz Qs Qv, replace
mata
lp = LinearProgram()
                
                P = (Pz, Ps, Pv)                // probabilities
                Q = (Qz, Qs, Qv)                // marginal distributions
                m = cols(P)
                n = rows(P)

                X = J(m, n , .)
                eq_l = sum(X) ; eq_r = Q 
                // has to be out of the loop                                          
                                                // bounds
                                                
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
  // ----------------------------------------------------
                                                // coefficients
                
                
                coefs = (Pz, Ps, Pv)
                
                                                // equality constraints
                eq_lhs =  (1 , 1, 1) ;    eq_rhs = 1
                
                lower =   (0,    0,     0)
                upper =   (1,    1,     1)


// ----------------------------------------------------
                                             // set class
                
                lp.setMaxOrMin("max") 
                lp.setCoefficients(coefs)
                lp.setEquality( eq_lhs,   eq_rhs)
                lp.setEquality(  eq_l,   eq_r)
                lp.setBounds(lower, upper)

               // ----------------------------------------------------
                                            // solve linear program

                lp.optimize()
                lp.parameters()
                X[i,.] = lp.parameters()    // Store parameter
}
                // ----------------------------------------------------
                                            // done

                // Return solution as vector (x, value_of_objective_function)

                X
                st_matrix("coefs", X) // export to STATA
end
//getmata X
```

Comment: Since X is binary, surely there's no way to make it sum to Q.

Comment: Are Q and R perhaps swapped?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, while I took the sum of X out of the loop. But for swapping Q and R I did not know what u meant. Q should represent the marginal distribution and R were ranks, but I replaced them with the original probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think your LP construction is probably missing a constraint: since this is an assignment problem, you need to set a maximum X row sum of 1 for the assignment to be exclusive.

I don't have Mata so I cannot contribute to fixing up your dimensional issues, but I can show you what an equivalent solution in Scipy would be. The constraint matrices are sparse, and the exclusive assignment constraint uses a Kronecker product.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint
import scipy.sparse as sp

P = np.array((
    (.02268130, .8045667, .172752000),
    (.09679342, .8531785, .050028090),
    (.06026781, .8577851, .081947100),
    (.15252922, .8199771, .027493654),
    (.24786794, .7403268, .011805267),
    (.02268130, .8045667, .172752000),
    (.09538278, .8537293, .050887900),
    (.05995392, .8576999, .082346160),
    (.08492604, .8570921, .057981850),
    (.09858042, .8524512, .048968350),
))
Q = np.array((3, 5, 2))
m, n = P.shape

constrain_qsum = LinearConstraint(
    A=sp.hstack((sp.eye(n),)*m, format='csc'),
    lb=Q, ub=Q,
)
exclusive_assign = LinearConstraint(
    A=sp.kron(sp.eye(m), np.ones(n), format='csc'),
    ub=np.ones(m),
)

result = milp(
    c=-P.ravel(), integrality=1, bounds=Bounds(lb=0, ub=1),
    constraints=(constrain_qsum, exclusive_assign),
)
assert result.success, result.message
X = (result.x.reshape((m, n)) > 0.5).astype(np.int8)
print(X)
```

```
[[0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```